# Why is my picture being rotated with this script?

Tags: php

Not sure what the heck is going on?? But if I have a lager picture uploaded (portrait) style, then it crops it and then rotates it?? What am I missing. It would be nice just to have a max_width and let the ratio do the rest?? Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
    function uploadImage($fileName, $maxSize, $maxW, $fullPath, $relPath, $colorR, $colorG, $colorB, $maxH = null){
        $folder = $relPath;
        $maxlimit = $maxSize;
        $allowed_ext = "jpg,jpeg";
        $match = "";
        $filesize = $_FILES[$fileName]['size'];
        if($filesize > 0){  
            $filename = strtolower($_FILES[$fileName]['name']);
            $filename = preg_replace('/\s/', '_', $filename);
            if($filesize < 1){ 
                $errorList[] = "File size is empty or too big";
            }
            if($filesize > $maxlimit){ 
                $errorList[] = "File size is too big.";
            }
            if(count($errorList)<1){
                $file_ext = preg_split("/\./",$filename);
                $allowed_ext = preg_split("/\,/",$allowed_ext);
                foreach($allowed_ext as $ext){
                    if($ext==end($file_ext)){
                        $match = "1"; // File is allowed
                        $NUM = time();
                        $front_name = substr($file_ext[0], 0, 15);
                        $newfilename = $front_name."_".$NUM.".".end($file_ext);
                        $filetype = end($file_ext);
                        $save = $folder.$newfilename;
                        if(!file_exists($save)){
                            list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($_FILES[$fileName]['tmp_name']);
                            if($maxH == null){
                                if($width_orig < $maxW){
                                    $fwidth = $width_orig;
                                }else{
                                    $fwidth = $maxW;
                                }
                                $ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;
                                $fheight = $fwidth/$ratio_orig;

                                $blank_height = $fheight;
                                $top_offset = 0;

                            }else{
                                if($width_orig <= $maxW && $height_orig <= $maxH){
                                    $fheight = $height_orig;
                                    $fwidth = $width_orig;
                                }else{
                                    if($width_orig > $maxW){
                                        $ratio = ($width_orig / $maxW);
                                        $fwidth = $maxW;
                                        $fheight = ($height_orig / $ratio);
                                        if($fheight > $maxH){
                                            $ratio = ($fheight / $maxH);
                                            $fheight = $maxH;
                                            $fwidth = ($fwidth / $ratio);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if($height_orig > $maxH){
                                        $ratio = ($height_orig / $maxH);
                                        $fheight = $maxH;
                                        $fwidth = ($width_orig / $ratio);
                                        if($fwidth > $maxW){
                                            $ratio = ($fwidth / $maxW);
                                            $fwidth = $maxW;
                                            $fheight = ($fheight / $ratio);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                if($fheight == 0 || $fwidth == 0 || $height_orig == 0 || $width_orig == 0){
                                    die("FATAL ERROR REPORT ERROR CODE [add-pic-line-67-orig] to <a href='http://www.atwebresults.com'>AT WEB RESULTS</a>");
                                }
                                if($fheight < 45){
                                    $blank_height = 45;
                                    $top_offset = round(($blank_height - $fheight)/2);
                                }else{
                                    $blank_height = $fheight;
                                }
                            }
                            $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($fwidth, $blank_height);
                            $white = imagecolorallocate($image_p, $colorR, $colorG, $colorB);
                            imagefill($image_p, 0, 0, $white);
                            switch($filetype){
                                case "gif":
                                    $image = @imagecreatefromgif($_FILES[$fileName]['tmp_name']);
                                break;
                                case "jpg":
                                    $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES[$fileName]['tmp_name']);
                                break;
                                case "jpeg":
                                    $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES[$fileName]['tmp_name']);
                                break;
                                case "png":
                                    $image = @imagecreatefrompng($_FILES[$fileName]['tmp_name']);
                                break;
                            }
                            @imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, $top_offset, 0, 0, $fwidth, $fheight, $width_orig, $height_orig);
                            switch($filetype){
                                case "gif":
                                    if(!@imagegif($image_p, $save)){
                                        $errorList[]= "PERMISSION DENIED [GIF]";
                                    }
                                break;
                                case "jpg":
                                    if(!@imagejpeg($image_p, $save, 100)){
                                        $errorList[]= "PERMISSION DENIED [JPG]";
                                    }
                                break;
                                case "jpeg":
                                    if(!@imagejpeg($image_p, $save, 100)){
                                        $errorList[]= "PERMISSION DENIED [JPEG]";
                                    }
                                break;
                                case "png":
                                    if(!@imagepng($image_p, $save, 0)){
                                        $errorList[]= "PERMISSION DENIED [PNG]";
                                    }
                                break;
                            }
                            @imagedestroy($filename);
                        }else{
                            $errorList[]= "CANNOT MAKE IMAGE IT ALREADY EXISTS";
                        }   
                    }
                }       
            }
        }else{
            $errorList[]= "NO FILE SELECTED";
        }
        if(!$match){
            $errorList[]= "File type isn't allowed (ONLY JPG or JPEG) : $filename";
        }
        if(sizeof($errorList) == 0){
            return $fullPath.$newfilename;
        }else{
            $eMessage = array();
            for ($x=0; $x<sizeof($errorList); $x++){
                $eMessage[] = $errorList[$x];
            }
            return $eMessage;
        }
    }

    $filename = strip_tags($_REQUEST['filename']);
    $maxSize = strip_tags($_REQUEST['maxSize']);
    $maxW = strip_tags($_REQUEST['maxW']);
    $fullPath = strip_tags($_REQUEST['fullPath']);
    $relPath = strip_tags($_REQUEST['relPath']);
    $colorR = strip_tags($_REQUEST['colorR']);
    $colorG = strip_tags($_REQUEST['colorG']);
    $colorB = strip_tags($_REQUEST['colorB']);
    $maxH = strip_tags($_REQUEST['maxH']);
    $filesize_image = $_FILES[$filename]['size'];
    if($filesize_image > 0){
        $upload_image = uploadImage($filename, $maxSize, $maxW, $fullPath, $relPath, $colorR, $colorG, $colorB, $maxH);
        if(is_array($upload_image)){
            foreach($upload_image as $key => $value) {
                if($value == "-ERROR-") {
                    unset($upload_image[$key]);
                }
            }
            $document = array_values($upload_image);
            for ($x=0; $x<sizeof($document); $x++){
                $errorList[] = $document[$x];
            }
            $imgUploaded = false;
        }else{
            $imgUploaded = true;
        }
    }else{
        $imgUploaded = false;
        $errorList[] = "File Size Empty";
    }
?>
<?php
    if($imgUploaded){
        echo '<img src="/eb_admin/images/success.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" style="margin-bottom: -4px;" /> Success!<br /><img src="'.$upload_image.'" border="0" /><input type="hidden" name="full_story" value="'.$upload_image.'" />';
    }else{
        echo '<img src="/eb_admin/images/error.gif" width="16" height="16px" border="0" style="margin-bottom: -3px;" /> Error(s) Found: ';
        foreach($errorList as $value){
                echo $value.', ';
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the image you're uploading is properly oriented. Don't just look at the embedded thumbnail, which can be in the wrong orientation. Some images can also have a rotation flag set internally, so they display properly, but are actually stored in rotated format. GD will go from original picture data and ignore such flags.

Otherwise, nothing looks obviously wrong with your code. Though, I would put the `getimagesize()` call outside the resize block to make it part of your initial error checking. Right now you're assuming the image can be read/loaded. If the image can't be read, getimagesize returns false and you can save yourself work later.

comment followed up:

somewhere around here:

```
if($filesize > $maxlimit){ 
    $errorList[] = "File size is too big.";
}

// put it here
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($_FILES[$fileName]['tmp_name']);

// additional error check
if ($width === FALSE) {
   $errorList[] = "Could not read image";
}

if(count($errorList)<1){
   etc...
   // and when it comes time to actually use the width_orig/height_orig later in this
   // block, they're already set from the earlier getimagesize() call
```

Comment: hmm.. where do I put the getimagesize() ?? Below or above??